# How do I call an expression statement without assigning

Tags: javascript, expression, anime.js

I'm trying to work with the library AnimeJS but ran into some issues in regards to how javascript works. I'm not super familiar with Javasript, but I'm trying to create stand-alone functions that returns an animation. These functions are then placed inside an array so I'm able to iterate through them all.

But the problem is that I'm not able to call an expression statement because I dont assign it to a button like I do on play-btn and test-btn.

```
function GamePiece1() {
    return anime({
        targets: '.p1',
        translateX: 270,
        loop: false,
        autoplay: false
    });
}

function GamePiece2() {
    return anime({
        targets: '.p9',
        translateX: 270,
        loop: false,
        autoplay: false
    });
}

var allAnimations = [
    GamePiece1,
    GamePiece2
];  

function resetAllAnimations(){
    allAnimations.forEach(function (anim) {
        anim().reset;
    });
}

document.querySelector('.play-btn').onclick = GamePiece1().play;
document.querySelector('.test-btn').onclick = GamePiece2().play;
document.querySelector('.pause-btn').onclick = resetAllAnimations;
```

Inside the function "resetAllAnimations" I wish to be able to iterate through all animations and call the .reset. When I try to do it this current way I get the warning: Expression statement is not assignment or call.

I don't know if there is a way to work around this and make it possible so I hope that someone here can help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `.reset`? If that refers to a function, it's expecting you to call it, `.reset()`. Simply declaring it like that will only do something if it's actually a *getter* which has side effects, which is weird

Comment: @CertainPerformance You are right, it is a function. Do you have any suggestions to ways I can achieve my goal?

Comment: Like I said, just call it - `.reset()`

Comment: Unrelated but can `play` function be called without an `anime` object as `this`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance it didn't work. But what about when I call "play" on the buttons. They seem to work just fine, is it because they are not functions but something else?

Comment: @adiga I've tried and it doesn't seem so

Comment: Got it working adding () to my functions in my array and calling reset. Thanks guys!

Comment: You need to use a wrapper or `.bind` in that case. Check Nina's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use the return value/object of the call of the function and work with this value. Otherwise you create always a new animation.

```
function GamePiece1() {
    return anime({
        targets: '.p1',
        translateX: 270,
        loop: false,
        autoplay: false
    });
}

function GamePiece2() {
    return anime({
        targets: '.p9',
        translateX: 270,
        loop: false,
        autoplay: false
    });
}

var gamePiece1 = GamePiece1(),
    gamePiece2 = GamePiece2(),
    allAnimations = [gamePiece1, gamePiece2];  

function resetAllAnimations(){
    allAnimations.forEach(function (anim) {
        anim.reset();
    });
}

document.querySelector('.play-btn').onclick = gamePiece1().play;
document.querySelector('.test-btn').onclick = gamePiece2().play;
document.querySelector('.pause-btn').onclick = resetAllAnimations;
```

Or if the last part does not work, you could wrap the event function in a function.

```
document.querySelector('.play-btn').onclick = () => gamePiece1().play();
document.querySelector('.test-btn').onclick = () => gamePiece2().play();
```

Comment: This was perfect, all I had to do was to add () to my array of functions. Must have missed that thanks a lot!